# What to call a facelift demonstration performed on an actual live volunteer as opposed to a mannequin?

Tags: phrase-request

What do I call a "**live** demonstration" of a facelift procedure, in which **live** means "on a human volunteer" and not "via the Internet" or "on a mannequin"?

I'm translating a Russian text describing such a demonstration for training purposes.

Maybe "human volunteer demonstration"? Will it fit?

Comment: By "demonstration" do you mean like a performance with people (students) watching?

Comment: @JamesK - yes, surgery students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A live, clinical demonstration of a facelift".  "Clinical" to mean "in the clinic  or operating room" as opposed to "in a lecture theatre".

You might also say "non-simulated", as "simulated surgury" is a common training technique.

> Students are trained by observing live clinical demonstrations of facelift procedures on human volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

I think typically these are called "[in vivo](https://www.lexico.com/definition/in_vivo)", in medicine. This means that the procedure is being performed on a live subject.

So you might say "The facelift demonstration is being performed in vivo on a human." Or if it's obvious it's being performed on a human, then just "The facelift demonstration is being performed in vivo."

Comment: Indeed. The sequence [***in vivo demonstration***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+vivo+demonstration&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=20) is quite well-established.

Comment: well established but completely the wrong context!  This refers to, for example, a proof (demonstration) that a medicine works as expected when tested on an animal.  The word "demonstration" means this is not an in vivo demonstration that a drug works.